# Print text conditionally if argument is not empty

Tags: conditionals, pgfkeys

I would like to define a command with arguments managed using `pgf-key` that prints some text conditionally on the the fact that a value was indeed passed.
Here is my current code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}


\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{
  /mycommand/.is family, /mycommand,
  default/.style = {optional={}},
  optional/.estore in =\OPTIONAL,
}

\newcommand{\COMMAND}[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/mycommand, default, #1}%
  Xyzzy ! \OPTIONAL{}  happened. % This text should only appear if optional is not empty
  }

\COMMAND[optional=Nothing]

\COMMAND[] % This should not print anything.

\end{document}
```

I suppose the next step has to do with `.is if`. But testing for emptiness seemed unexpectedly complex. Can this be achieved in a simple manner?

Answer (score 2):

You can test for emptiness

```
\newcommand{\COMMAND}[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/mycommand/.cd, default, #1}%
\if\relax\OPTIONAL\relax\else Xyzzy ! \OPTIONAL{}  happened.\fi% 
  }
```

But the idea of the key-value syntax is to avoid such stuff. Instead use a `/.code` and branch out with a `/.default` handler if nothing is given.

Comment: I am beginning with pgf-keys. Do you mean that the test can be avoided altogether? I did not found out how to use /.code and /.default here.